# Receiver ListUrl is not working in Event Receivers for particular list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, event-receiver

I trying to debug EventReceiver is not working. It use to work properly. Only thing I changed is added Intraner AAM.

http:// spfoundation/dept/it/Lists/App%20Change%20Request/AllItems.aspx

Above url is the default AAM and list url.

```
<Receivers  ListUrl="Lists/App%20Change%20Request">
  <Receiver>
    <Name>AppChangeEventReceiverItemAdded</Name>
    <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
    <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
    <Class>AppChangeRequest.AppChangeEventReceiver.AppChangeEventReceiver</Class>
    <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
  </Receiver>
```

```
public class AppChangeEventReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An item was added.
    /// </summary>
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
       // base.ItemAdded(properties);
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            try
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList list = web.Lists["Project/Task Status Details"];

                 ......
                 ......

               web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

In visual studio 2012, I was able to debug properly. Now I am not. Anything wrong I did here? Breakpoint not reaching even first line of it. "No symbols have been loaded..."

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try

1- Delete the dll of your project in GAC (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL)

2- Deploy project again

3- Control the dll if its the last deployed one.(control the date)

4- From the vs2012 
    -debug and attach to process (w3wp.exe and OWSTIMER.exe)

if this does not work, restart vs2012 and try steps again.

I hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

It may be a late answer but still. I killed half of a day figuring out very similar issue in my environment. It is really possible that if AAM is set up incorrectly, event receivers won't be fired (although the site is loaded and everithing works well... well, almost everything). In that case you'll probably find an error like this in the event log:

Event receiver threw an exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at http://xxx.yyy.zzz/sites/aaa could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.